# What's the meaning of the parameter -e for bash shell command line?

Tags: bash, shell

I have as bash shell script with header `#!/bin/bash -e`.

When I run the script, it will be interrupted after the `grep` command runs, but when I remove the parameter `-e`, then the script can be run normally. What is the meaning of parameter `-e`?

Comment: @MitchWheat However there is [no `-e` option for bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) so, what is really happening in this case? :(

Comment: It is indeed not obvious, but there *is* a `-e` option for bash: http://serverfault.com/questions/391255/what-does-passing-the-xe-parameters-to-bin-bash-do.

Comment: Only one point more. For example, when you find this: [ -e filepath ] Returns true if file exists.

Answer (score 154):

The `-e` option means "if any pipeline ever ends with a non-zero ('error') exit status, terminate the script immediately". Since `grep` returns an exit status of `1` when it doesn't find any match, it can cause `-e` to terminate the script even when there wasn't a real "error".

If you want to keep the `-e` option, but also have a `grep` command that might validly find no matches, you can append `|| :` to the `grep` command. This means "or, if the `grep` command returns a non-zero exit status, run `:` (which does nothing)"; so the net effect is to disable `-e` for the `grep` command. So:

```
grep PATTERN FILE... || :
```

---

**Edited to add:** The above approach discards every error: if `grep` returns `1` because it found no matches, that's ignored, but also if `grep` returns `2` because there was an error, that's ignored, and if `grep` isn't in the path (so Bash returns `127`), *that's* ignored — and so on. So, rather than `:`, it's probably better to use a command that checks the result code and re-issues the error if it's something other than `1`. For example:

```
grep PATTERN FILE || (( $? == 1 ))
```

But this destroys the exit status; usually, when a failed command terminates a Bash script with `-e`, the script will return the command's exit-status, but in the above example, the script will just return `1`. If (and only if) we care about that, we can fix it by write something like this:

```
grep PATTERN FILE || exit_code=$?
if (( exit_code > 1 )) ; then
    exit $exit_code
fi
```

(first line c/o [dsummersl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214890/dsummersl)'s comment).

At this point, it's probably best to create a shell function to handle this for us:

```
function grep_no_match_ok () {
    local exit_code
    grep "$@" || exit_code=$?
    return $(( exit_code == 1 ? 0 : exit_code ))
}
```

(note the use of `return` rather than `exit`; we'll let `-e` handle the exiting when appropriate); this way, we can just write:

```
grep_no_match_ok PATTERN FILE     # won't kill script if no matches are found
```

In fact, since we most likely want to use this function for *all* occurrences of `grep` in this script, we can actually just name the function `grep`:

```
function grep () {
    local exit_code
    command grep "$@" || exit_code=$?
    return $(( exit_code == 1 ? 0 : exit_code ))
}

grep PATTERN FILE     # won't kill script if no matches are found
```

(note the use of `command` to bypass the shell function within its own body: we want the function to call the regular program `grep`, rather than to recurse infinitely).

Comment: Very nice. I've taken to using your advice to capture the exit code for later use: `grep XXX FILE || exitcode=$?`. Super handy!

Comment: @dsummersl: Cool, I'm glad you liked it! Your comment inspired me to expand my answer with some potential improvements that you might like.

Comment: Seriously, thanks for that. The pattern you outline is enlightening; its a nice pattern for guarding against unexpected exit codes while simultaneously ignoring expected ones...I can definitely see using this pattern to simplify the main flow of my scripts.

Comment: @ruakh Excellent answer, the grep function is really useful. Thanks.

Comment: Only one point more. For example, when you find this: 

[ -e filepath ] 

Returns true if file exists.

Answer (score 24):

From the [fine manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash):

> In addition to the single-character shell command-line options (see The Set Builtin), there are several multi-character options that you can use.

And then if we look at what [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) has to say:

> `-e`
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a subshell command enclosed in parentheses (see Command Grouping), or one of the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see Command Grouping) returns a non-zero status.

So when you say `bash -e`, if any command in the script fails (i.e. returns a non-zero exit status), then the whole script immediately fails. So your `grep` is returning a non-zero value because it isn't matching and that's shutting down the whole script if you specify `-e` when running bash.

Comment: Ah yes, I suspected this was from `set` but wanted to see it in the manual. I was wondering why I didn't see it in `man bash`, it's because I went straight to the options listed and missed the paragraph that said *"All  of the single-character shell options documented in the description of the set builtin command, including -o, can be used as options when the shell is invoked".* All there!